# How do I fully remove background from the <button> in CSS?

Tags: css

Imagine I have such a button:

```
#btnred{
color:#fd9898;
background:none;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;}
```

And when I hover on it, the box-shadow appears, but it appears behind the background of the button.

```
#btnred:hover{
box-shadow:0 0 10px  #605894;
transition:0.4s;}
```

How do I completely remove the background so that box-shadow appears right behind the text of that button?

Comment: Use `text-shadow`, not `box-shadow`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, that's what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

- remove the `box-shadow` entry in CSS
- and use `text-shadow` instead.

See reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-shadow/